# Product Images API

Tags: api, product

I'm using my app for product barcode scanning and storing product related meta-data.

I'm currently using `UPCDatabase` to get product information but this API does not give me any images.

Is there an easy image searching API to use in this scenario ? My first choice would have been the Google Image Search API but that has been deprecated..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm representative of http://aerse.com. Aerse provides API to get product images with the following features:

- They are taken from official sites.
- There is an API to get thumbnails
- Transparent images, that could be embedded into different designs

Here is the sample workflow:

1. Get product name from UPC database
2. Get Image link from Aerse using product name
3. Download/embed thumbnail/full image

Although Aerse has UPC search as well, it's UPC database has less data then `UPCDatabase`. Most of the official sources don't provide UPC/EAN codes.

Comment: Your site doesn't have a trusted certificate

Comment: We are working on enabling trusted SSL. Images however distributed via plain HTTP.

Comment: Website now down